SwiftUI .fileExporter only one can appear when there are multiple modifiers in the view tree
struct ContentView {
var body: some View {
   VStack {
       NestedView()
   }
   .fileExporter(isPresented: $showExporter1, document: document1, contentType: .someFileType, defaultFilename: defaultFilename) { ... }
}
}

In NestedView, there is another .fileExporter modifier
struct NestedView {
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button {
            showExporter2 = true
        } label: {
            Text("Export")
        }
    }
    .fileExporter(isPresented: $showExporter2, document: document2, contentType: .anotherFileType, defaultFilename: defaultFilename2) { ... }
}
}

Only the outer exporter can appear. The one in the NestedView won't appear. When the Export button is pressed, nothing happens.
EDIT:
I've tried to move the inner one right next to the outer one. Two .fileExporter modifiers attached to the same view. But only the last one can show.
Is there any way to show different file exporter when user pressed different button?
EDIT2:
Finally solved the problem. It seems .fileExporter cannot coexist in nested view structure. As @Sweeper pointed out, it works when two .fileExporter attached to sibling views.

So just don't nest fileExporters? What do you want to ask?

@Sweeper I edited the question. The question is how to show different exporter dialog using two different condition variables...

So just put the fileExporter modifier directly on the buttons, not their parent.

@Sweeper Also tried that. It doesn't work

Please show a [mcve] of that, because it totally worked for me. Just to be clear, it's two Buttons in a VStack, and each Button has a fileExporter attached.

@Sweeper the first button is in a Menu. If the first fileExporter is attached to the button, it won't show because when pressed the menu disappears and modifier will be disposed immediately.

Great, now we are getting somewhere. Please [edit] your question with that information.
